# .Net Maui: StorageWrite permission stops working with .net 7 on Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

It worked on .NET 6, but now when I migrated my .net maui project to .net 7 the problem starts occurring: I have MediaPicker placed to one xaml page of my project in order to capture a picture and store it at the app data directory. I can run Android emulator and get permission for camera, but it stopped working for storage. I deleted and re-created Android emulator device, I tried different Android versions like API 29, 33, but nothing works. I used to pop up Android permission dialog window automatically when it executes `CapturePhotoAsync`, now it does not, and even when explicitly request the permission it still does not show dialog window and retuns `Denied` immidiatelly

```
// got PermissionStatus.Denied, no dialog window requesting permission pops up
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
```

If I ignore it and tries to store the picture it predictably raises the exception `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.PermissionException: 'StorageWrite permission was not granted: Denied'`

Anyone can suggest what could be wrong and what can I try to get it resolved

**UPDATE**: created min. project and uploaded it to the github: github.com/YMichurin/mauiStoragePermissions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is specific to Android 13 with MAUI, and the open issue is here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11275

Using the Android 12 emulator or below should work.

Comment: right, I've just realized it too. first time I had API 33 installed, then I decided to install earlier versions as per @LiyunZhang recommendation and it worked, I thought it was some env. issue on my machine

Answer (score 3):

I have done a sample to test with your code. And the permission request dialog will show after I clicked the button.

Did you forget to add the permission into the AndroidManifest.xml? Such as:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In addition, you can create a new project with the .net 7.0 to test the code. It worked well in my project.

**Update**

When I cloned your project to the vs, there was some packages errors. And the project run successfully after I added the following code into the csproj.cs.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0-rc.2.22430.11" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0-rc.2.22430.11" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0-rc.2.22430.11" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0-rc.2.22430.11" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And the **Result**:

[image]

The console log:

[image]

The permission request dialog will show and the picture saved successfully after I granted the permission.

Comment: thank you for checking that @Liyun. I have the permission set and it perfectly worked in .net 6, before the migration. I'll try to create brand new project and let you know

Comment: Did it work in the new project? @YMC

Comment: no, it did not help unfortunately, same issue, I tried different Android emulators. I uploaded the project here https://github.com/YMichurin/mauiStoragePermissions, could you please take it and try on your machine?

Comment: Please check the updated answer and I run it on the android 12 emulator. @YMC

Comment: interesting. While referencing these packages and rebuilding solution did not help me, your actions helped me to understand that something is deeply broken in my dev environment, so I reinstalled VS along with SDKs and Maui workload. Now the solution works, the dialog window is back. Thank you, I appreciate your help