# MAUI: FileSaver save to SD Card on Android (emulator) delivers path of built in storage as FilePath in result

Tags: c#, android, maui

My App has "All files access"-permissions. The App uses the `CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaver` to save files (`Save As ...`) also to the SD Card which works.
But

```
var fileSaverResult = await FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync(dirname, fileName, stream, ct);
if (fileSaverResult.IsSuccessful)
{
    filename = fileSaverResult.FilePath;
    // ...
```

always delivers the path of the build in storage, even if saved to SD Card.
So if the user presses `Save`, the file is stored now to the build in drive (using `filename`) and not to the SD Card as he would expect.

Note: Because of [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11275) and the proposed workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74342624/net-maui-storagewrite-permission-stops-working-with-net-7-on-android-emulator) I use Android API32 in the `AnroidManifest.xml`

I use the CommunityToolkit.Maui version 5.1.0.

Any ideas how to get the SD card path after the FileSaver saved to it?

**Update**:

dirname and fileName are just starting points. The FileSaver calls the built in android Files-app. Then the user can navigate in this app (like in the Windows Explorer) e.g. to the SD Card and even change the file name

You could start with
`dirname = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents"` (points to the built in storage)
`fileName = "MyFile"` or both could even be empty strings.

In addition the FileSaver (or the built in android Files-app) does not take the dirname into account. If dirname is changed during debugging to `/storage/170B-2B04/Documents` (170B-2B04 is the SD Card-ID on my emulator instance) the Files app still opens at the built in storage. But this is another question ...

Comment: `SaveAsync(dirname, fileName,` Should we guess what value you gave those variables?

Comment: `delivers the path of the build in storage, ` You better tell which path exactly. Value.

Comment: `ideas how to get the SD card path after the FileSaver saved to it?` Strange question. I would assume that you determined that path before with variables dirname, fileName.

Comment: Are you doing this in the Android Emulator or on a physical device?  I've managed to re-create what you're seeing in the emulator, can't test physical as my device doesn't have an SD Card.  It could potentially be a bug with the CommunityToolkit, it has.. a few.

Comment: @Laim: I only used the emulator.

Comment: `So if the user presses Save, ...`  What you did not tell is that the user navigated to the micro sd card and then to a directory on it.

Comment: The Files app will never give you a path. You will obtain an uri.

Comment: @blackapps: But the FileSaverResult has the FilePath as a string. So may be it translates the Files app result not correctly.

Comment: There is nothing to translate i would say.

Comment: I implemented an Android specific workaround based on a workaround for a `Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePicker` issue 
referenced here (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6015#issuecomment-1533657234) 
without the Blazor specifics. Since it is quite lengthy I would only publish it here if it is of interest.